# Hardcoding a 3d array for rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a slot machine program for my java class and I realized that I need to make a 3d array in order to make the correct payouts. I am having trouble hardcoding the array. I want to be able to use it almost like coordinates if that helps. I had it as a 2d array before I wanted to change it so here is the format that I had for that.

String[][][] wheelArray = new String[][][]

```
{   {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
    {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
    {"Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bell","Bar"} 
    };
```

Comment: Good grief.  Create a class to generate one wheel of a slot machine, and construct 3 instances of the class for the 3 wheels.

Answer (score 0):

This only needs to be a two dimensional array. The first dimension should represent which slot you are trying to reference (out of 3), and the second should represent the fruit you are trying to reference. Your code, as is, will work for a 2D array. If there is some other variable you haven't mentioned in your question that we need to consider that requires a 3D array, please let me know.

```
String[][] wheelArray = new String[][]
{{"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
{"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
{"Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bell","Bar"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is probably the wrong data structure for your purpose, but to use an array here you have to understand the meaning of each dimension. You didn't tell us what those were - image type, row on the slot machine, ...?

In general to initialize a 3-index array you use a similar notation to what you showed, but with three layers rather than two:

```
{ { {CHERRY, CHERRY, CHERRY}, {CHERRY, CHERRY, PLUM}, {CHERRY, PLUM, PLUM} },
  { {PLUM, PLUM, PLUM}, {PLUM, PLUM, LEMON}, {PLUM, PLUM, BAR} },
  { {CHERRY, PLUM, BAR}. {CHERRY, PLUM, LEMON}, }, 
}
```

It would be much better to create a custom structure, actually several, including an 'enum' for the symbols (such as CHERRY, PLUM, LEMON, BAR).

How exactly are you dividing the data into three dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

If you need 3D it can be :

```
String[][][] wheelArray = {

        {
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bell","Bar"}
        },

        {
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bar"},
                            {"Cherry","Cherry","Plum","Plum","Bell","Bell","Bar"}
        }
};
```